# Project organization for .net core local development

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am relatively new to dotnet development and have a problem how to setup my local dev environment. I have a asp net core rest api, that uses different "services" internally. The project ist relatively huge so we have split our services into external libraries which we pull in via dependencies. That works perfectly fine. The only problem i have is when integrating a new service or when developing new features of an existing service and i want to build / test the api with my new locally build service.

Is this possible? What would be an easy was to handle this use case? Removing the external dependency and adding a local one during development? I googled and searched here on stackoverflow but did not find any solution.

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Sebastian

Comment: Just to clarify something. You are creating class library which you use as a nuget package? How would you update the external libraries in your local host? let's say for example to add a new feature or fix a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the `Condition` attribute on the `ItemGroup` element on my csproj file in combination with some sort of local flag files. The csproj config looks like:

```
<!-- erp service -->
<ItemGroup Condition="Exists('..\.localdev_erp')">
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\erp-svc\MyCompany.Service.Erp\MyCompany.Service.Erp.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="!Exists('..\.localdev_erp')">
  <PackageReference Include="MyCompany.Service.Erp" Version="1.0.9" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The files can easily by created and removed locally, only a `dotnet restore` may required after adding / removing a local reference. Small drawback to this solution is that a somewhat homogenous local environment is required for all the developers.

We use this solution for the following use cases:

- integration / onboarding of new services
- explorative programming of the new features / technologies
- bug hunting in the integration layer, may require to write regression tests on both sides, the api and the service.

Comment: Good solution. I would use `Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' "` and then no local flag files are required

Answer (score 1):

To debug `nuget packages` you can use [symbols packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages-snupkg) to publish symbols along with with your `dlls`. `Visual studio` supports symbol sources that allow to download symbols and debug the source code. But the problem can be deeper...

Ideally the external library should have a stable interface that can be tested by auto tests that are near the library itself. Even significant changes shouldn't cause any changes and problems in the calling code. In that case removing the external dependency and adding a local one during development should be OK since it is very rarely action.

If you need to debug your packages very often usually it means that both parts get changed together often. It can signal the problems listed below:

1. Your code and code of the package have high coupling. The boundary between modules is selected unsuccessfully. In that case consider to redesigning both parts to make them more independent and decrease the coupling. Independent parts usually don't require to debug them together.
2. Both parts have high cohesion. In that case you definitely need to keep it together.
3. Library has an unstable interface. In that case keep it together until the interface becomes stable.

Comment: I agree with you that most of the times the case i have isn't really needed. Most of our libs have stable interfaces and good testing coverage. What i need is a solution for easy integration a new lib with our existing external api.